# rust: adding a field to an existing struct with serde_json

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I have a pre-defined struct

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo<T> 
where T: Serialize
{
    foo: T
}

struct Bar{
    a: String
}

struct Bar2{
    b: String
}

fn main() -> Result<()>
{
    let a1 = Bar {a: "something".to_owned(),};
    let a2 = Bar {a: "something2".to_owned(),};
    let a_vec: Vec<Bar> = vec![a1, a2];
    let b = Bar2 {b: "something"}
    let b_vec: Vec<Bar2> = vec![b];
    //let foo = Foo {foo: vec![a_vec,b_vec]}

}
```

How can I put both struct under `Foo` or is it possible to first serialize `Bar` to json and add `Bar2` as string literals? The result would be a json

```json
{"foo": [{"a": "something"}, {"a": "something2"}], "b": "something"}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. The output you want is there, but the constraints of your question are unclear.

Comment: I agree, the output also seems to be slightly at odds with what you seem to be asking for. The output show has a top level `"foo"` key with the `Bar` value under it and then another top level `"b"` key that seems to be the `Bar2` struct value. Could you clarify what the shape of the output you are looking for is?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, the constraints are 1)no modification of struct 2)output JSON, and I'm also wondering if I can put both `Bar` & `Bar2` under `Foo`? I thought a solution of serializing both structs to `serde_json::Value` first and merge them but I am not sure if there are better solutions regarding to `struct` or `serde`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this serialized structure by storing both `Foo` and `Bar2` in another struct and *merge* them together with `#[serde(flatten)]`. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3f72c00768dc0ac8060bcf622a86cac5)):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo<T>
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    foo: T,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Bar {
    a: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Bar2 {
    b: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Outer<T: Serialize> {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    field_1: Foo<T>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    field_2: Bar2,
}

fn main() {
    let a1 = Bar {
        a: "something".to_owned(),
    };
    let a2 = Bar {
        a: "something2".to_owned(),
    };
    let a_vec: Vec<Bar> = vec![a1, a2];
    let b = Bar2 {
        b: "something".to_owned(),
    };

    let o = Outer {
        field_1: Foo { foo: a_vec },
        field_2: b,
    };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&o).unwrap());
}
```

```
{"foo":[{"a":"something"},{"a":"something2"}],"b":"something"}
```

If instead by *"no modification of struct"* you meant by only serializing `Foo` and just modifying `T`, then no its not possible to get that output with `serde` directly. You'd have to do your proposed method by serializing into `Value`s and merging them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

- You haven't derived `Serialize` for `Bar` and `Bar2`.
- You're trying to put `a_vec` and `b_vec` into a vector, which you can't do because they're of different type.

The latter problem can be solved by dynamic dispatch. Instead of putting `a_vec` into the `Vec`, you put `&a_vec as &dyn Serialize`, i.e. just give it a reference to some serializable object. Slight trouble is that this won't work with `serde::Serialize` because it's not object safe. This is what `erased_serde` is for:

```rust
let foo = Foo::<Vec<&dyn erased_serde::Serialize>> {
    foo: vec![&a_vec, &b_vec],
};
println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&foo).unwrap());
```

will work fine. But it will output

```json
{"foo":[[{"a":"something"},{"a":"something2"}],[{"b":"something"}]]}
```

which is not what you wanted?

To get the output you wanted, i.e. serialize Foo and add a field to it, you could use `#[serde(flatten)]`:

```rust
let foo = Foo { foo: a_vec };
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Merge<T1: Serialize, T2: Serialize> {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    f1: T1,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    f2: T2,
}
let out = Merge { f1: &foo, f2: &b };
println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&out).unwrap());
```

The output of serializing `Merge` both the fields from `T1` and `T2`.